# D3.js dynamically scaled and position image in node

Tags: javascript, d3.js

**Is it possible to dynamically position and scaled an image based on node size?**

I am working with circle nodes that have dynamically sized font for each node:

```
node.append("text")
      .attr("dy", ".2em")
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text(function(d) { return d.className; })
      .style("font-size", "1px")
      .each(getSize)
      .style("font-size", function(d) { return d.scale + "px"; });

function getSize(d) {
  var bbox = this.getBBox(),
      cbbox = this.parentNode.getBBox(),
      scale = Math.min(cbbox.x/bbox.x, cbbox.y/bbox.y);
  d.scale = scale;
}
```

**Is this same effect acheivable with an png image?** The goal would be to have each node with an indivially specific image that is automatically scaled and positioned above our current text.

Every image will be the same size but have different content. Example 175px X 50px and will be scalable down or up to the appropriat node size. Like:
[image: goalExample] 
But each image will be unique to the node it is in. Currently, I have been trying:

```
node.append("image")
    .attr("xlink:href", "http://www.wepushbuttons.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/gimp-logo.png")
    .attr("x", -8)
    .attr("y", -100)
    .attr("width", 16)
    .attr("height", 16);
```

---

My current code(node/text) dynamically scales to size the above image code does not. I am thinking there is a way to encode IMAGE `.attr("dy", ".1em")` just above the text and something with `this.getBBox()` To scale the width:175 and height:50 to the appropriate size for the node.

- **Is this possible?**

Answer (score 2):

Use a pattern to create an pattern / image which dynamically scales with the parent, and set it as a fill:

```
<svg width="300" height="300">

  <defs>
    <pattern id="image" width="1" height="1" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
      <image xlink:href="http://placekitten.com/200/300" width="100" height="100" preserveAspectRatio="none"></image>
    </pattern>
  </defs>

  <circle id="catball" fill="url(#image)" r="60" cx="100" cy="100"/>

</svg>
```

When you adjust the r, the filled pattern will also expand.

The key is in use of the [viewBox attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox), set to the same width and height as the containing image. Since we're just going to be filling depending on the parent anyway, we just set them all to 100.

You can read up on svg patterns here: http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/pservers.html#Patterns

Example with crazy expanding cat here: http://jsfiddle.net/nPwx3/

Comment: I am unable to get it to work with any of my code. It may be me but this only allowse for 1 image per svg. I need 1 image per node in the 1 svg correct me if I am wrong. [Tested Code](http://i.stack.imgur.com/6efCD.png "Screen capture") No scaling and not in each node... I will update my request/question...

Comment: Create a unique id for each image you want to use - see pattern id="image1", you can have image2, image3, cute-cat.. whatever you like. Then, set the url(#{id name goes here}) as the fill.